# сортировка односвязного списка C++

Tags: c++

помогите, пожалуйста, с сортировкой односвязного списка.
есть структура студент, формат фамилия_имя_отчество_возраст_успеваемость.
нужно сделать сортировку по фамилии.
ниже прикреплю свою неудачную попытку, саму структуру и небольшой кусок программы.

```
struct student
{
 string name;
 string surname;
 string middlename;
 float progress;
 int age;
 struct student* next;  
 };

struct list {
 student st;
 list *next;
 };

void Print(list *b)
  {
    list *print = b;
    while (print != NULL)
{
    std::cout << print->st.surname << " " << print->st.name << " "
    << print->st.middlename << " " << print->st.age << " "       
    << print->st.progress << endl;
    print = print->next;
}
std::cout << "NULL\n";
}

 void sort(list **begin)
 {
  list *t = new list;
  list *t2 = *begin;
  t = *begin;      

    while (t != 0)
    {
            list *t1 = t->next;
        if (t1->st.surname < t2->st.surname)
        {
            list *tmp = t2;
            t2 = t1;
            t = t2;
        }
        t = t->next;

}
}

int main()
 {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
  SetConsoleCP(1251);
  SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
  forward_list <student> st;
  list* begin = NULL;
  list* head = nullptr;
  list* item = nullptr;

   for (;;) {
    int x = menu();
    switch (x) {
    case 1:
    {
        Print(begin);
        break;
    }
    case 8:
    {
        sort(&begin);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Во первых, если вы не инициализировали поля  структуры, вы никак не сможете сравнивать.  Что с чем сравнивать ,  как сортировать и что сортировать?.. Ваш код оставляет только одни вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, у вас есть: структура с именем студента. То что вы именовали `list` - это не список. Вообще вы как то странно поступили: создали этот `list`, его передаете в функцию сортировки, но при этом список создаете из структур `student`. Короче будем считать, что список это:

```
forward_list <student> st;
```

Что вам нужно, чтобы его отсортировать? Для начала нужно его наполнить, но это чисто ваша ответственность.

1) Операция больше или меньше для структур типа `student`.С этим вообще никаких проблем, так как это зависит только от имени, а имя определено как `string`, для которого уже есть эти операции

```
bool operator>(student &a, student &b)
{
    return a.name > b.name;
}
```

2) Нужна функция сортировки. Для этого, в самом простом варианте, просто проходите список от начала до конца и сравниваете два рядом стоящих элемента, если первый больше, чем второй (для этого и нужна операция `>`), то меняете их местами. И так несколько раз, пока весь список не будет отсортирован.

Comment: можете объяснить, чем неправильна структура list?

Comment: я просто разбирался в теме по видео, там примерно так все объяснялось.
список ст, по идее, вообще не нужен.

Comment: Ну вот смотрите: у вас есть ваша структура list - как по ней итерироваться? Эти элементы, конечно можно связать, но вот только, раз они указывают только на следующую структуру, как пройти к предыдущему элементу? Это не список, а ветка. Список же обязательно должен содержать корень. К тому же, как я понял из вашего кода, вы используете списки из стандартной библиотеки. Хоть я ими никогда не пользовался, но раз вы их изаете, то зачем вообще эта структура list?

Comment: так список же односвязный, здесь должна быть разве ссылка на предыдущий?

Comment: вы не дочитали: я писал, что список должен содержать корень. Односвязный список на то и односвязный, что в нем элементы указывают только на следующий элемент. Но! Как с вот таким вот списком, как у тебя, ты собирался работать? Как, например, добавить туда элемент? Или изъять? Как найти нужный? Это - не список, а нода для списка. Сам список будет чем-то вроде: `list {node *root; node *last; unsigned size;};`. Таким образом мы будем иметь непосредственный доступ к первому элементу, для итераций; к последнему, для быстрого добавления; к размеру списка, для того, чтобы знать его размер.